# Bound on the faces in a trapezoidal map

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry

Consider a trapezoidal map used in point location algorithms in computational geometry, as follows:

Consider $n$ 2D line segments. Two line segments are said to be non crossing if their intersection is either empty or one of the end points. All the $n$ line segments are non crossing pairwise. Also no two distinct end points in the set of endpoints of those $n$ segments have same $x$ coordinate. Now enclose all the line segments in an axis parallel rectangle. Draw two vertical lines from each end point. Those verticals stop either at the outer rectangle or when they meet another segment. Create a vertex at each of such intersections. Each face in this planar graph is either a triangle or a trapezoid.

Suppose there were $n$ segments. Also, assume that the entire graph is inside an axis parallel to a rectangle. Now, according to the text Computational geometry, Algorithms and applications by Mark de Berg et al. the upper bound on the number of vertices is $6n+4$ . This I get. It's also stated there that the upper bound on the number of faces is $3n+1$ . The proof given there is not based on Euler's formula for planar graphs, but the authors hint that the bound can also be proved using the said formula by using the bound on the vertices.

Now Euler's formula for a planar graph is f >= 2+e-v. If e and v are **not** independent, it is not necessary that f reaches maximum when e reaches maximum and v reaches minimum. Even if they are independent, I don't get how upper bound on faces is attained when number of vertices reaches it's maximum. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you explain what "a trapezoidal map used in point location algorithms in computational geometry" is, and possibly show an example? (It's not even clear to me from this context whether you mean map in the sense of "a map of England" or map meaning function or something else).

Comment: Consider n 2D line segments. Two line segments are said to be non crossing if their intersection is either empty or one of the end points. All the n line segments are non crossing pairwise. Also no two distinct end points in the set of endpoints of those n segments have same x coordinate. Now enclose all the line segments in an axis parallel rectangle. Draw two vertical lines from each end point. Those verticals stop either at the outer rectangle or when they meet another segment. Create a vertex at each of such intersections. Each face in this planar graph is either a triangle or a trapezoid.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry for the ambiguity. I thought trapezoidal maps are part of the standard terminology in computational geometry.